# Add data from database to Data Grid

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, datagridview, datagrid

I want to fetch data from sql server database and show it up in a Data grid view with edit and delete links how should I go about it?

Comment: Is this VB or C#? Have you tried anything? If so show some code. If not the question is too broad as you are asking us to write the code for you.

Comment: have you tried something?

Comment: I have tried getting data from database and I fill that data to dataset I don't know how I can assign that dataset to data grid

Comment: @onkarsahas that's simple `GridView1.DataSource = yourdatase;   GridView1.DataBind();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1>First to access database records prepare connnection string

2>Write query to retrieve records from data table

3>And Finally bind that record to into dataGridView

To do all above steps follow this link

[Click Here](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2010/12/v-behaviorurldefaultvmlo_27.html)

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of doing it. If you search a little you could've found many option :-D

Anyway, These links would give you most of the options we use with GridView to bind data from a Database.

www.tomot.de/en-us/article/7/asp.net/gridview-overview-of-different-ways-to-bind-data-to-columns

http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/ASP.NET/0380__Data-Binding/DataBindingtoGridViewC.htm

Comment: You can post these links as a comment, as these links may change..

Comment: Yeah good point. Will do that next time